# How to deallcate memory allocated to a list?

Tags: c++, list, memory-management, memory-leaks, stdlist

How do we free memory allocate to a list?  In the following code even after clearing the list and deleting the pointer to the list, it doesn't free the memory. I can see the memory taken by the program in the system monitor. 
Is there an efficient way to delete the memory allocated to the list?

```
struct Plot
{
    int BUFFER[65535];
    int BUFFER1[65535];
    int BUFFER2[65535];
    int BUFFER3[65535];
    int BUFFER4[65535];
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::list<Plot> *LIST= new std::list<Plot>();


    Plot PLOT;
int i=0;
while(i<1500)
{

    (LIST)->push_back(PLOT);
    i++;
    usleep(100);
}


LIST->clear();

delete LIST;

while(1)
{
    usleep(100);
}
}
```

Comment: The allocated memory is freed correctly, there is no leak. You cannot rely on the system monitor for this because the internals of the C++ library hide a lot of things, for example the freed memory may not be returned immediately to the system, but the library could just put it in it's own free memory pool and do subsequent allocations from that pool rather than requesting the memory directly from the system. It's totally implementation dependent.

Comment: Consider using a custom allocator if tight memory management is a concern for you.

Comment: This is just a sample code. I've similar code where the memory is increasing infinitely.  Valgring also shows memory leak at the new operator.

Comment: @RajatSati there may be another problem in that other code. Try to put the content of your `main` function into a infinite loop, I'm sure the memory usage won't increase indefinitely.

Comment: Don't use new, especially not for std containers. Don't use owning raw pointer.

Comment: @RajatSati *std::list<Plot> *LIST= new std::list<Plot>();*  -- What if there is an exception thrown after this call, and you don't get to the `delete LIST` line of code?  You've created a memory leak for yourself by doing things like this.  Use a smart pointer or not use pointers at all and just use value semantics.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the program should stop in that case, shouldn't it, as there is no exception handler.

Comment: @MichaelWalz -- *I've similar code where the memory is increasing infinitely.* -- That's what the OP claims.  If they're doing stuff like this in the rest of the app, then ...

Comment: Show us where the infinite loop is. If it is around the list new (and you only delete after the loop) then that is a leak. In the fact, your code as shown does not need to have `new std::list` at all, you can just use a simple std::list variable. You need to show the minimal example which actually demostrates the issue (i.e. and example which will trigger Valgrind to report the leak as you state - I'd guess the code as posted does not trigger the Valgrind leak report even for you).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie OK, I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Michael Walz ,@PaulMcKenzie  We are also storing some data in to application's internal stores, which could explain the increasing memory uses . So is there a way to check that or some tool which can tell where the memory is being used.

Comment: @RajatSati maybe valgrind?

Answer (score 1):

This slightly modified program is just running on my Windows machine.

Try this on your platform and see what's happening.

(Disclaimer: this is terrible code, just in order to stick to the OP's code.)

```
#include <list>
#include <windows.h>

struct Plot
{
  int BUFFER[65535];
  int BUFFER1[65535];
  int BUFFER2[65535];
  int BUFFER3[65535];
  int BUFFER4[65535];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 0;

  while (1)
  {
    printf("Iteration %d\n", i++);

    std::list<Plot> *LIST = new std::list<Plot>();

    static Plot PLOT;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 1500)
    {
      (LIST)->push_back(PLOT);
      i++;
    }

    LIST->clear();
    delete LIST;

    Sleep(100);
  }
}
```

And this is the memory usage vs time that the system monitor shows me (one division is 1.6 Gb.):

[image]

And this is what the system monitor shows me when I run the same program compiled in release mode instead of debug mode, it's entirely different, because the internal implementation of the memory allocator is totally different in release mode:

[image]

But as we can see, the memory is correctly freed in both versions and the program is still running in the background.